# How to delete an item from recycler view which gets data from Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[image: here is my database structure]

When I delete an item from recycler view using a button, it is deleting the last item present in the list and not the one which i need to delete.

Below code is my adapter.

```
holder.itemRemoveTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //delete
                deleteProduct(productId); //ID is the  product  id
            }
        });


 private void deleteProduct(String id) {
        //delete product using its ID
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Cart").child(id).removeValue()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        //product deleted
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Removed from Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        //deleting product failed
                        Toast.makeText(context, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
        cartList.remove(id);
        //notifyItemRemoved(id);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
     
    }
```

How do I delete the exact item with a button click?

Now, even when I press the delete button of the 1st item, it is deleting the last item only. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Comment: Besides that, does the `productId` variable hold the exact ID of the product you want to delete? If no, how to do you get that ID?

Comment: yeah. Im getting that product ID from my model class. Please refer below.

String productId = cartModel.getItem_PID();

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate the exact value of  `productId`.

Comment: Yes bro .. I have added the db structure as a snippet.

Comment: If you try to use the hard-coded value, is the corresponding product deleted?

Comment: I haven't tried this scenario

Comment: Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242400/discussion-between-e-kart-shop-and-alex-mamo).